# Laravel Nova Progress Metrics Issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

In Laravel Nova Progress Metrics I percentage will be shown I want to show the value there
see the image for reference[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3s30.png)

```
public function calculate(NovaRequest $request)
{
    $totaCount = User::count();
    return $this->count($request, User::class, function ($query) {
        return $query->where('user_status', 'pending');
    }, target: $totaCount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to use the included query helpers for building your value metric, you may easily manually provide the final values to the metric using the result and previous methods, giving you full control over the calculation of these values:

```
return $this->result(
  // query and resul calculation
);
```

https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/metrics/defining-metrics.html#manually-building-value-results